# Sub class unable to change super class property in typescript

Tags: typescript, inheritance

I know this is probably a silly error or I am expecting something that's wrong, nevertheless I am stumped as to what I am missing here. I am new to typescript and I am trying to optimize my Angular app by doing some inheritance jazz.

So here is what I want to achieve. I have a base component that needs to provide data to one of its drop down boxes but the data is to be provided by a child component (only the child knows what the list values should be based on some login and other criteria). So here is what I did and what I thought would work

```
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit
{
  public list!: string[]; // this is needed for a drop down in my html

  constructor(protected service: SomeService) { //injecting service for other tasks in super}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //console.log(this.list) is always empty
  }

  public setList(list: string[]) {
    this.list = list;
  }
}

export class SubComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit
{
  constructor(
    service: SomeService,
  ) {
    super(service);
    super.setList(this.service.getDropDownList1());//only sub class which method to call, like xxxList1 or xxxList 2 etc

  }
}
```

But on my ngOnInit in the super, list is always empty. I just do not understand why? Given that I am explicitly calling super to set a property on super why does this not work? I have been struggling with what I though was a rudimentary issue but I do not see any way around. Can you please help?

Thanks,
Ananth

PS : In the super class constr, if I explicitly call

```
this.service.getDropDownList1()
```

the list is populated and shows fine in the html. But via the sub class no luck :(

Also putting console.logs in both constructors and onInits, I noticed that base constructor is getting called twice, dont know why that is happening - probably due to my explicit super call????

EDIT 1:
Given that I am from a pure Java background, let me see if I can explain my problem with an example from there!

```
 class Super {
  String superStr = "";

  public Super()
  {
    System.out.println(" in super constr" + this.superStr);

  }

  public void setString(String s)
  {
  this.superStr = s;
  }

  protected void printStr(){
    System.out.println("in printStr of super" + this.superStr);
  }
}

public class Sub extends Super{
  
  public Sub(){
  super.setString("I am sub setting super str");
  }

public static void main(String[] args){
  Sub s = new Sub();
  s.printStr();
}

}
```

In this case, s.printStr prints the value set in the call to super's setString method. That is what I was expecting to happen in my TS code too. In constr the sub sets the super's list, and on onOnit being called the list will be used to display drop down values. Am I comparing wrongly? Just wanted to make sure I understand this. So would appreciate if you can help me understand what I am getting wrong.

EDIT 2:
I am accepting Chris' answer below - his guidance was the most helpful towards me getting a grip on how things work!

Comment: is  `this.service.getDropDownList1()` sync/async?

Comment: Actually that is populated right at login time. Long before the html displaying the drop down is even accessed. And anyway its sync (populated while user authentication)

Comment: If you pass in the same service that the sub uses to get the list, why not have the parent class do that?

Comment: Like I said, parent class has no idea what xxxListX method to call. Only the sub components know it based off the user login type and other criteria. Plus I want to abstract that responsibility to the sub components

Comment: Your java example is correct, but it is not the same as your typescript. Change `Sub s = new Sub()` to `Super s = new Super()`. This is the mistake you made by instantiating the base class instead of the sub class. In your html you put `<app-base></app-base>` instead of `<app-sub></app-sub>` correct?

Comment: @ChrisHamilton I am sorry but I still do not see it, apologies in advance. I want the sub comp to contain the base comp, so my sub comp html does have ```<app-base></app-base>``` in it. Are you saying that is wrong? When the components are rendered wont the constructors get invoked? Doing the change you suggest from Sub to Super in Java will never work as I expect because sub's constr is never called, hence no super setList. So that is clear. But in TS, the sub's constr will get called during the lifecycle right? I wish I understood this and not have to bug you more :(

Comment: Having the `<app-base>` inside your sub component creates a separate component. So you have 1. An instance of a sub component and 2. An instance of a parent component. They are two separate instances, they do not communicate via inheritance, and they do not share html.

The sub's constructor gets called by the `<app-sub>` component and not the `<app-base>` component. Changes you make to the sub component will not affect the html rendered by the `<app-base>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code into stackblitz and it seems to be working fine.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-spjlo9?file=src/app/sub/sub.component.ts

Does your html contain the tag for the sub component? In other words, are you sure you're displaying the sub component and not the base component?

Although I do see a discrepency here:

```js
super.setList(this.service.getDropDownList1());
```

I needed to delete `this` or I got a compile error

```js
super.setList(service.getDropDownList1());
```

Alternatively you can label the service as `protected` like the super. Not sure if that was just a typo while copying.

Comment: Actually the html I am using is for the base component. Not the sub component. The functionality is such that the base component displays a list of common filter drop downs (the various listXXX methods for different drop downs). So all the drop downs are defined in the base component's html only. Why is that a problem? And if that is a problem then inheritance is moot here right. I will end up replicating these filter drop down in each sub components' html files. That is what I am trying to avoid and hoping inheritance would solve the issue. I saw your code and your list is used in sub html :(

Comment: in fact the way my html is designed is to include the base comp html and then below it add a summary grid based off the values selected in the filter drop downs in the base comp. This way I was hoping that I can reuse the base comp for all other sub components that need the same filter panel. Is that design thinking wrong? Also the filter drop downs have some logic for enabling/disabling etc which I wanted to abstract into the base comp so that the logic is one place and no code duplication. Wonder what I am missing, please guide me!

Comment: Yes, you're misunderstanding inheritance. An instance of a child class (sub-component) inherits properties / functions of the parent class, but an instance of a parent class (base component) does not inherit anything from child classes. The constructor of the sub-component is inaccessible from an instance of the base component.

Comment: I think you may also be missing the point of components. There is generally no need for inheritance when it comes to components. If they have common properties such as a filter panel, you can make the filter panel its own component, and add the tag to the html of any other component.

Comment: Thank you Chris for the clarifications. I have 2 questions. Firstly, does the super.setList have no effect on the super's list property. If you remove inheritance as a concept, it is pure parameter passing, correct? So why does the base component lose the list data set by the sub component? Secondly, I started off by doing it the way you said - a new comp with the filter panel. But the overheads of passing data from the sub component into this common component led me to the point of using the base comp itself as the common component. From a design thinking, why is that wrong?

Comment: kindly see my edit, hopefully that clarifies my confusion! Or maybe is it all timing - when onInit of super comp is called to render the html the list is empty. GIven that I am new to angular this side of things are hazy for me. Maybe it works as I expect it to, just that while rendering the drop down has no values even though the sub comp has set them

Comment: See my comment on the main thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241706/discussion-between-ananth-and-chris-hamilton).